# Apache this site cannot be reached

Tags: apache, dns

I have unknown error on my server. I have installed LAMP, but I can't connect there. I get error `DOMAIN’s server DNS address could not be found.`

Here is my error.log

```
[Sun Apr 02 15:54:46.846874 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 16260] AH00169: caught SIGTERM, shutting down
[Sun Apr 02 15:54:47.894232 2017] [mpm_prefork:notice] [pid 26586] AH00163: Apache/2.4.7 (Ubuntu) PHP/5.5.9-1ubuntu4.21 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Sun Apr 02 15:54:47.895090 2017] [core:notice] [pid 26586] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
```

Is there any way to fix it?

Comment: Have you read the error message? Did you try to check DNS servers?

Comment: It caused randomly, I added my script on the server. Enabled .htaccess files and then it happened. I "reverted" steps I did, but it never went "away".